# Minimal PIC32 program is huge

Tags: c, cmake, compilation, mips, pic32

I am trying to get a simple embedded PIC32MX "Hello, World!" program to compile without using MPLAB X.
For Chip-support, I am using the [spicastack/pic32-parts-free](https://gitlab.com/spicastack/pic32-parts-free) library. Which is as far as I can see, just a redistribution of Microchip's XC32 header files.

With the following minimal cmake file I can get the program to compile just fine:

```
project(pic32example C ASM)
include_directories(pic32-parts-free/include)
add_compile_options(-mips32 -EL -nostdlib -Os -D__PIC32MX__ -D__32MX570F512L__)
set_source_files_properties(pic32-parts-free/proc/32MX570F512L/p32MX570F512L.S PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-x assembler-with-cpp")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}.elf
    main.c 
    pic32-parts-free/proc/32MX570F512L/p32MX570F512L.S
)
```

main.c :

```
int main(void) {
    /* Very boring program */
}
```

Calling cmake with `cmake -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/mipsel-linux-gnu-gcc -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/mipsel-linux-gnu-g++ ..` compiles the program. However, the size of the resulting elf file is much bigger than I'd expect. Even after I call `mipsel-linux-gnu-strip` on it:

```
$ ls -lah
143K Mar 16 09:19 pic32example.elf           # unstripped simple program
 84K Mar 16 09:09 pic32example-stripped.elf  # stripped simple program
```

On further inspection it looks like there is a lot of debugging information for dynamically linking glibc (roughly 23KiB of it). and it looks a lot like the rest of the program is just doing nothing. I dont use anything from glibc so I'd like that part to be cut out, but `-nostdlib` doesn't seem to affect it.

So my question is: How come the program is so huge in spite of it doing absolutely nothing? And what compiler flags should I use to get it down to a reasonable size? (Other than `-Os` and `-nostdlib`)

> NOTE: If you want to recreate my setup, [spicastack/pic32-parts-free](https://gitlab.com/spicastack/pic32-parts-free) does not provide the assembler file that I use, but if you swap it out with `pic32-parts-free/proc/32MX440F256H/p32mx440f256h.S` in the cmake file it should compile. The resulting binary should be about 63KiB before stripping. Still way too big for such a small program.

Comment: Is this the only gcc compiler port for that target? Do they have a "No EABI" version as the case with ARM?

Comment: You can try to add -g0 to disable debug info.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200292/process-for-reducing-the-size-of-an-executable

Comment: @Lundin I haven't looked at that yet. Thanks!

@Devolus If I recall correctly `strip` would remove debug information. Also, thanks for the link!

Comment: I would use something like `objdump` to see what is taking up the space